# Save local db data to server on end of the day

Tags: android, time

I am trying to save local db data to server on end of the day.But the problem is mobile user can change the date and time from settings. So i can't take the system time as correct time.How i synchronize the server time and the application time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GMT Date :

```
public static Date getGMTDate(String dateFormat) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

        // Local time zone
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

        // Time in GMT
        return dateFormatLocal.parse(dateFormatGmt.format(new Date()));
    }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////

```
public static Date getCurrentServerDate(String dateFormat, int min) {
    Date date = null;
    String TimeFormate = "HH:mm:ss";
    try {
        date = getGMTDate(TimeFormate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    return calendar.getTime();

}
```

i hope this is useful to you....

my edited ans:
when you call this method as following method:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        int int_TimeZoneOffset = Integer.parseInt(TIMEZONE_OFFSET);
        String TimeFormate = "HH:mm:ss";
        Date CurrServerdate = CommonMethod.getCurrentServerDate(TimeFormate,
                int_TimeZoneOffset);
        Log.i("CurrServerdate", "CurrServerdate=" + CurrServerdate);
```

i hope this is useful to you....

Comment: I am getting Thu Jan 01 13:07:54 GMT+00:00 1970 as date.Is there anything that i want to add in this method?

Comment: from where i will get TIMEZONE_OFFSET?can you suggest an example